# onRefresh swiperefreshlayout in fragment call my main activity class method to replace my fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, static, swiperefreshlayout

I am using swiperefreshlayout in fragment class I want to call My main Activity Method which replaces the fragment
but when i tried to declare a static method in main activity

```
mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

it shows

> non static method `getSupportFragmentManager()` cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: make non-static method and use activity object to call it, (MainActivity activity= (MainActivity) getActivity(); activity.yourMethod())

Comment: It Works!!! Thank you very Much...!

Comment: cheers.. happy coding....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

Make non-static method and use activity object to call it.

eg:

```
  MainActivity activity= (MainActivity) getActivity();
     activity.yourMethod();
```